Access denied from subfolder to root sub folder
I have my site structure as follows:
mysite.co.uk/admin/file.php
my images are stored:
mysite.co.uk/files/images/product/
The problem I am facing is the the code on the
mysite.co.uk/admin/file.php will not let me read the images in the products folder:
My code is as follows:
 $dir = "../files/images/product/";
    $dh  = opendir($dir);
    while (false !== ($filename = readdir($dh))) {
        $files[] = $filename;
        }
    sort($files);
    foreach ($files as $filename){
  echo "<option value='". $filename . "'>" . $filename . "</option>"; 
   }

Please any advise is welcome
I can see the files stored in ../files/images/ when changing the $dir to ../files/images/product the server send a HTTP502 error, which seems a bad gateway.
I have tried to allow url files/images/product in the firewall however that doesnt work either.
I have also tried to change the permission on the actual folder 0755 to 0644 but that caused a lot more problems
The server is godaddy.
Please any advise is welcome

This question is confusing. Please invest a it of time to clear things up, try to be as precise as possible. How else can you expect to get a clear answer? 1. "will not let me read the images" ... what does that actually mean? Does you option select you compose contain any options or not? If not, what does your error log contain? 2. are you sure you receive the http status 502 when trying to setup that options select? That would mean that the "products" folder is not part of the regular file system. 3. what kind of "firewall" offers you to "allow url"? 4. "lot more problems" - which are?

Do not use relative pathes.. you are assuming something (the current working directory), that might not be as expected on another environment. If that directory is relative to the file from which it is referenced, make it relative to __DIR__, aka: $dir = __DIR__ . '/../files/images/product/';
